# Fab button not working

Tags: android, android-studio, android-listfragment, floating-action-button

My Activity **MainFragment** extends **ListFragment** and it creates items using this part of code

```
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater()
                    .inflate(R.layout.list_item_drs, parent, false);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.dateTextView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.drs_dateTextView);
            holder.dsMainDisplay = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.cloud_MainView);

            getListView().setDivider(null);
            getListView().setDividerHeight(0);
            getListView().setSelector(android.R.color.transparent);

            convertView.setTag(holder);

        }else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        Cloud c = getItem(position);

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

And I wanted to put Fab button on top|bottom position of main view so I used **onCreateView** method to inflate my created xml layout **list_view** where I described Fab button

```
@TargetApi(11)
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view,null);

    FrameLayout fl = (FrameLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view, parent,false);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) fl.findViewById(R.id.addNew);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick (View view) {

            //Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), AddActivity.class);
           // getActivity().startActivity(i);

    }

    });
```

**list_view xml** this code is in FrameLayout when I use other types of layouts it disappears

```
<ListView android:id="@id/android:list"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/addNew"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:useCompatPadding="true"
    app:elevation="5dp"
    app:pressedTranslationZ="0dp"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"/>
```

Now Fab button appears in right position and stays in place when I scroll through list but now it doesn't show any response. Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the fab is defined in the `list_view.xml` then you have to access it by

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) v.findViewById(R.id.addNew);
```

then the `onCreateView` must return the view just inflated, that is,

```
return v;
```